# Cmake run a ExternalProject if find_package fails

Tags: cmake, ncurses

I am writing an application that requires ncurses, and I have it setup to build ncurses (among others) as external projects:

```
ExternalProject_Add(ncurses-extern
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ncurses
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/mirror/ncurses.git
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix <INSTALL_DIR> --with-normal --without-debug --without-manpages
    BUILD_COMMAND make -C <BINARY_DIR>
    INSTALL_COMMAND make -C <BINARY_DIR> install
)

add_library(ncurses-lib INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(ncurses-lib INTERFACE -L${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ncurses/lib -lncurses)
target_include_directories(ncurses-lib INTERFACE ncurses/include)
```

However for this to work, however I either have to make it so ncurses-lib depends on ncurses extern which will make it so it runs the external project every time (even if its already installed), or I have to manually run it.

What I would like it to do is only run the external project to run, if A: ncurses can't be found on the system with find_package, or B: if ncurses doesn't already exist in the lib folder (where the external project puts it).

However I am not sure how I would achieve this, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `find(ncurses) \\ if(NOT ncurses_FOUND) \\ ExternalProject_add(...`?

Comment: This is wrong approach. You should make explicit option whether to use system-provided or bundled `ncurses`.